# Extract string from output command

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk

My program output is as the following:

```
# myprogram list
val
val.dev
val.int
val.int.p1
val.int.p2
val.int.p3
val.int.p4
val.int.p5
val.dev.p6
```

I want to extract from the above output only strings under `val.int.` so I want to add something to the command in order to get the following output:

```
# myprogram list|<something options>
p1
p2
p3
p4
p5
```

Is it possible to do it with `awk` (or someting similar like `sed`) in only one call of `awk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
awk -F'val.int.' '$0=$2' file
```

file contains your data:

```
kent$ awk -F'val.int.' '$0=$2' file
p1
p2
p3
p4
p5
```

Comment: should I have pass through file? because I tried `myprogram list|awk -F'val.int.' '$0=$2'` and I didn't get anything

Comment: @AhmedZRIBI either you're typing something wrong or there's something you're neglecting to tell us, because both this and tstone's answer work. Does your command do something different in a pipeline? Try `myprogram list | cat` and see if it's the same output.

Answer (score 2):

```sh
awk 'NF>2 {print $3}' FS=.
```

- change field separator to `.`
- print field 3

Answer (score 2):

```
myCommand | sed -n 's/val\.int\.//p'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution, this one involving `grep` and Perl regular expressions:

```
$ myprogram list | grep -Po "(?<=val\.int\.).*"
```